# Sampling from a Poisson distribution (infinite support)

Tags: sampling, poisson-distribution, discrete-distributions

I would like to sample from an infinite discrete distribution, i.e. Poisson distribution
\begin{align}
\Bbb P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is a fixed parameter.

In case of a finite distribution I could use ALIAS method, but it doesn't work in this case. I've found that I could use a transformation
\begin{align}
X=\min\{ k: U \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i \}
\end{align}
but is that the way to go?

Comment: With arbitrary accuracy, which you may select, you *can* use the alias method.  Just truncate the distribution at, say, its $1-10^{-16}$ quantile.  Another approach is to sample from a mixture of a more severely truncated version of the distribution and the remaining tail (recursively).  The recursion has probability $1$ of terminating (and will terminate rapidly).

Comment: An extremely efficient method of obtaining such a sample is given (with `R` code) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/606853/919, exhibiting an ordered sample of size $10^{100}.$ If the sequence of results matters, take such a sample and randomly permute it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a quite surprising way to sample from the Poisson distribution with any $\lambda$ parameter.  The basis for this is the following algorithm to sample a Poisson variate with $\lambda = 1$, which involves only integer arithmetic and no floating-point operations (Duchon and Duvignau, "Preserving the number of cycles of length *k* in a growing uniform permutation", Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 23(4), 2016):

1. Set *ret* to 1, *a* to 1, and *b* to 0.
2. Generate $j$, a uniform random integer in [0, *a*].
3. If $j<a$ and $j<b$, return *ret*.
4. If $j=a$, add 1 to *ret*.  Otherwise, subtract 1 from *ret* and set *b* to $1+a$.
5. Add 1 to *a* and go to step 2.

Poisson variates with other $\lambda$ parameters follow by splitting $\lambda$ into pieces of size no greater than 1.  Then, for each piece, a Poisson variate with $\lambda$ equal to that piece is generated.  Then all these variates are added together.

Finally, let $\mu < 1$, then to generate a Poisson variate with parameter $\mu$, it's enough to:

1. Generate $N$, a Poisson variate with parameter 1.
2. Flip $N$ coins that each show heads with probability $\mu$, then count the number of heads.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly. This is known as *inverse transform sampling*, and [this earlier thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/307686/1352) may be helpful.

Actually, you have a typo in your formula (note that there is only a single $k$ and a single $n$ in your formula). What you would do is to generate a value $p$ that is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, and then the resulting Poisson variable $k$ is the smallest $k$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^kp_i\geq p$. You would of course pre-tabulate your $p_i$ up to some sufficiently large number, so you don't need to recalculate them multiple times.