# Test for "discrete normality"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption

I have implemented what I believe to be a sampler from a distribution over the integers. Its a specific discretization of the normal distribution so I know stuff like mean and variance of the theoretical distribution, and I can compute an approximate of the theoretical pmf but it's expensive so I can't do it for a lot of values. I'd like to gain some confidence that my sampler is actually sampling from the right distribution, preferably in a reproducible way (so no looking at histograms etc). what's a reasonable test for this?

I'm mostly overwhelmed by the variety of available statistics and the search for one that is defined for discrete distributions yet tells me something about "normality".

Comment: Could you explain what might be "expensive" about computing the PMF?  It could only be if you have millions of integers with appreciable probabilities, in which case you can replace the PMF by the Normal density to very great accuracy.  If you just want to test the accuracy of your sampler, what's the matter with the standard Chi-squared test?

Comment: @whuber How would a non-arbitrary $\alpha$ be chosen for such a test?

Comment: @Galen ? What does $\alpha$ refer to?  If it's an acceptable false positive error rate, that would be determined by the complement of "some confidence" mentioned in the question.

Comment: @whuber You've anticipated that I meant what is sometimes termed the "significance level", but I should have indicated that for clarity. It is that very notion of 'acceptable' which seems nebulous to me without assigning it to be coupled to something non-arbitrary. I guess the OP will have to decide what they find acceptable.

Comment: OP: If you are sampling from a normal distribution and then discretizing, doesn't the change of variables take care of getting the right distribution? If I have $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and I am interested in sampling from the distribution induced by the expression $\lfloor X \rfloor$, I need only sample from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ using existing tools and apply the transformation. Or is the discretization procedure itself numerically unstable with the float precision you're using?

Comment: @whuber The theoretical PMF involves an infinite sum, so all I can do is approximate it, and more accuracy means more computation. How would I decide that I'm close enough, e.g. for the chi-squared statistic to have an "acceptable" error?

Comment: @Galen This sampler produces values in a way that differs from the method you propose, and this results a different distribution that has properties I require. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "change of variables" here!

Comment: Could you please explain how a discretization of a Normal distribution requires an infinite sum to compute?  If you generate a large number of realizations and they still pass the chi-squared test, that's acceptable error, especially if you create bins (in advance) to focus on the portion of the distribution that matters most in your application.

Comment: @hanna Certainly I didn't mean that your transformation is the floor round, nor is my point special to floor rounding. If you have a random variable $X$ with CDF $F_X$ and you compose a measurable function $g$ then $g(X)$ itself has a CDF $F_{g(X)}$. If you sample from $F_X$ and transform the samples with $g$ then you have sampled from $F_{g(X)}$. See [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Random_Variables) for more info on change of variables in probability theory.

Comment: @whuber My imagination is lacking on an application right now, but abstractly one could consider maps $g:S_{\mathbb{R}} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ where $S_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a partition of the real numbers. Among such possible functions I could see some of them having non-compact preimages requiring series expansions for doing change of variables. This approach violates an intuition or connotation that discretization should preserve some kind of contiguity or adjacency, but I am not aware of a formal definition of discretization.

Comment: @hanna Can you share what the discretization procedure actually is? That would answer whuber's question, and satisfy my own curiosity. It'll also improve the chances of getting an answer to your original question.

Comment: @Galen The most general concept of discretization I have run across is tantamount to a measurable transformation $h:[a,b]\to\mathcal D$ where $[a,b]$ is the support of a distribution $F$ and $\mathcal D$ is a discrete subset of real numbers.  The *discretization* $[F]_h$ of $F$ has $\mathcal D$ for its support and for all $d\in\mathcal D,$ ${\Pr}_{[F]_h}(d)=\Pr(h(X)=d).$ (Always $h$ is monotonic, but it needn't be.) Thus, calculating these probabilities comes down to a calculation using $F.$ But whether anything like this is meant is a matter of speculation, because we haven't been told.

Comment: The distribution and sampler pseudocode are described in this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00010
It is not a discretization in the way you describe, but a discrete distribution that converges to the normal distribution with growing resolution. Sorry for the confusion.
@whuber The PMF is equation (1) on page 3 and requires an infinite sum to compute.

Comment: Although the normalizing constant might be *defined* in terms of a sum (much as, say, the exponential function is defined as a sum), you don't need that sum to compute  it.  It is expressible in terms of a Jacobi Theta function, whose properties are well studied.  Moreover, unless $\sigma$ is huge, there will be such a small number of terms in the sum that it can be approximated quickly with great accuracy with a finite partial sum.  Just summing over $y$ for which $|y-\mu|\le 8\sigma,$ for instance, gives double precision results. This is why details matter!

Comment: BTW, I believe a natural and extremely efficient method to sample from this distribution would use rejection sampling from the (obvious) dominating Gaussian distribution.

Comment: You can emulate the algorithm given in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/608790/919, which shows how to obtain *enormous* samples efficiently from any discrete distribution.  Use the code at "A quick test" to assess the accuracy of *any* sampling procedure.